# Chat list is not Refreshed After adding a new Friend and removing a friend from list using Asmack API in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, xampp, asmack

Hi I am using

> asmack-2010.05.07.jar for chating in android but my list is not refreshed after adding new friend and removing a friend. below I am using this code for chating

```
package com.demo.xmppchat;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.MessageListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Roster;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterEntry;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.MessageTypeFilter;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.PacketFilter;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Packet;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.RosterPacket.ItemType;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.StringUtils;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";
public static final String HOST = "talk.google.com";
public static final int PORT = 5222;
public static final String SERVICE = "gmail.com";
public static final String USERNAME = "" + "" + ""
        + "demo@gmail.com";
public static final String PASSWORD = "xxxxxx";
static String FRIEND = " " ;

public static final String friend_xmpp_id = "asdf@gmail.com";
public static final String friend_xmpp_id1 = "sfsfds.mca@gmail.com";
public static final String friend_xmpp_id2 = "sffasds@gmail.com";
public static final String friend_xmpp_id3 = "chipkali@gmail.com";
Button button;


public static String addfri;
public static String removefri;

// public static final String Friends = "";
public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> usersList;
ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;
private String USER_STATE;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    usersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(HOST,PORT, SERVICE);
    Constants.connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

    try {
    Constants.connection.connect();
    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
    }
    try {
    Constants.connection.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity","Logged in as " + Constants.connection.getUser());
    Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);

    Constants.connection.sendPacket(presence);
    setConnection(Constants.connection);
    Roster roster = Constants.connection.getRoster();

    Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();

    Log.i("size of entries", "size of entries===" + entries.size());
    for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {


        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Presence entryPresence = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());
        Presence.Type type = entryPresence.getType();
        map.put("USER", entry.getUser().toString());
        map.put("STATUS", type.toString());
        Log.i("USER", "Users Are::" + entry.getUser().toString());
        usersList.add(map);
    }

    roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {
        @Override
        public void presenceChanged(Presence arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


    //connection is XMPPConnection
    //friend_xmpp_id is friend id
    //Tags.XMPP_HOST is host name




        @Override
        public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        });

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, usersList);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    list.setAdapter(adapter);




    final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() { 

    @Override 
    public void run() { 
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    handler.postDelayed( this, 1 * 1000 ); 
    } 
    }, 1 * 1000 );


    Log.d("notifyyy", "data set change firing timer now ................................... ");


    // Click event for single list row
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
            HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();

            song = usersList.get(position);
            Log.i("getting user  FRIENDDDDDDDDDDDDD name is====", "===="+ song.get("USER"));
            FRIEND = song.get("USER");
            //String Friend = song.get("USER");




            Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
            Constants.connection.sendPacket(presence);

            Chat chat = Constants.connection.getChatManager().createChat(
            song.get("USER"), new MessageListener() {
            public void processMessage(Chat chat,Message message) {
            if (message.getType() == Message.Type.chat)
            System.out.println(chat.getParticipant()+ " says: " + message.getBody());
            }
            });
            /*
             * try { chat.sendMessage("hi........"); } catch (XMPPException
             * e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace();
             * }
             */

            Intent intent = new Intent(CustomizedListView.this,
                    XMPPChatDemoActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("HOST", "talk.google.com");
            intent.putExtra("PORT", 5222);
            intent.putExtra("SERVICE", "gmail.com");
            intent.putExtra("USERNAME", "hidost@gmail");
            intent.putExtra("PASSWORD", "iloveindiademo");
            intent.putExtra("FRI", FRIEND);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private void setUserPresence(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void setConnection(XMPPConnection connection) {
Constants.connection = connection;
if (connection != null) {
    // Add a packet listener to get messages sent to us
PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
            @Override
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
            Message message = (Message) packet;
            if (message.getBody() != null) {
            String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom());
            Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Text Recieved "+ message.getBody() + " from " + fromName);
            Constants.messages.add(fromName + ":");
            Constants.messages.add(message.getBody());
            // Add the incoming message to the list view
                }
            }
        }, filter);
        }

try {
    View.OnClickListener handler = new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //we will use switch statement and just
            //get thebutton's id to make things easier
            switch (v.getId()) {

                case R.id.button1: //toast will be shown
                   // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You Clicked Show Toast Button!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                    String newfri = friend_xmpp_id;
                    addFriend(newfri);


                    break;

                case R.id.button2: //toast will be shown
                       // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You Clicked Show Toast Button!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                        String remfri = friend_xmpp_id1;
                        removeFriend(remfri);


                        break; 

            }
        }



        private void removeFriend(String remfri) {
            //public void addFriend(String friend_xmpp_id)
            //usersList.clear();

            removefri = remfri;

            {
                try {
                    Constants.connection.getRoster().setSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.accept_all);
                    Constants.connection.getRoster().createEntry(removefri, removefri, null);

                    Collection<RosterEntry> entries = Constants.connection.getRoster().getEntries();
                    for (RosterEntry entry : entries) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("name..."+entry.getUser()+"...type.."+entry.getType());
                        if(entry.getType()==ItemType.none)
                        {
                            Presence unsubscribe = new Presence(Presence.Type.unsubscribe);
                            unsubscribe.setTo(removefri);
                            Constants.connection.sendPacket(unsubscribe);

                           // usersList.clear();
                            usersList.remove(removefri);
                            Log.d("removed"," the best friend " + removefri);



                      Log.d("size on removing" ," ................friendddddd" +  usersList.size());
                     // usersList.



                    }
                    }

                    System.out.println(" Are u sure u want to remove this friend from list "+removefri+"@"+HOST );
                } catch (XMPPException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }












        private void addFriend(String newfri) {
            //public void addFriend(String friend_xmpp_id)
            addfri = newfri;

            {
                try {
                    Constants.connection.getRoster().setSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.accept_all);

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Constants.connection.getRoster().createEntry(addfri, addfri, null);

                    Collection<RosterEntry> entries = Constants.connection.getRoster().getEntries();
                    for (RosterEntry entry : entries) 
                    {

                         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CustomizedListView.class);
                         startActivity(intent);


                        System.out.println("name..."+entry.getUser()+"...type.."+entry.getType());
                        if(entry.getType()==ItemType.none)
                        {
                            Presence subscribe = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribed);
                            subscribe.setTo(addfri);
                            Constants.connection.sendPacket(subscribe);




                        }




                    }

                    System.out.println("adding NEW FRIEND  friend ..................."+addfri+"@"+HOST );
                } catch (XMPPException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }




    };

    //we will set the listeners
    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(handler);
    findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(handler);

    }catch(Exception e){
         Log.e("Android Button Tutorial", e.toString());
    }  

}
        }
```

Comment: Please don't use a 4 year old aSmack version when there are up-to date releases available.